# How do I run a 5x8 McNemar chi square in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have data that is essentially a repeated measures chi square with 8 choices measured 5 times

```
library("descr")
library("lsr")

chidata <- matrix(c(129,67,113,11,41,3,12,23,79,37,99,28,42,2,10,4,48,43,44,29,39,3,10,2,18,13,12,17,25,3,10,1,5,7,2,6,7,10,10,10),nrow=8,ncol=5)

chidata

CrossTable(chidata,  mcnemar = T, chisq = T, resid = T, sresid = T, asresid = T)
```

While the Pearson chi square can be produced (even though there are 0s in the data, none of the expected values are 0, so it still runs), the McNemar cannot -- is there a way to run this as a repeated measures chi square?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need help choosing a more appropriate statistical test for your data, you should ask your question over at [stats.se]. The classic McNemar test is only defined for 2x2 tables so this isn't a programming question, it's a statistics question.

Comment: Will do... Thanks!